# Calculating Sensible Heat using Monin-Obukhov Similarity Theory (Stable Stratification)

Tags: energy-balance

I am calculating the sensible heat (H) using MOST and have run into a few problems.

[image]

1. First off, I calculated an initial H (from Rn-G-LvET) to start the iteration.
2. Using Eqn 2-5, I calculated u*(1), L(1), H (1) using Eqn 1 (L(1) > 0).
3. Repeat point 2 until L converges.

My problem is that my L never converges even though I have run >10,000 iterations. Another issue is that I get ridiculous H values (> & < 1000). Am I approaching this correctly?